# [android]how to keep connection with database?

Tags: android, mysql, sockets

I want to keep connection with database.

android side: It will know if there are any data is change on database.

I want the android app to show the newest data.
No need to do anything(eg:button on click).

Do I need to use socket service? or other?
any suggestion?
Which is easy to learn for a new.

I have a idea, use HttpClient to get json from php & database in every 1s.
Is it suitable?

Comment: Use LoaderManager and content provider.

Comment: If you dont have a backend and if you only need  a schema less backend you can go for firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to get data every 1 second (if that is what you meant) is asking for trouble. Mobile communications are not that reliable, if your customer goes through an area of poor reception, then your first request would not have timed out, before you have made 30 others.

I would suggest using `AlarmManager` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

or an Android `Service` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

polling the database no more than every 2 minutes. You could back this up with a manual "Sync" button that the user can click if the have a good data connection and are very impatient.